# registerActivityForResult unresolved reference kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, registerforactivityresult

I am using registerForActivityResult to signin using Google authentication API. For some unknown reason, the method is unresolved reference. I tried both options Appcompat and ComponentActivity.How can I resolve method `registerForActivityResult`? I get 'this' is not defined in this context when I use ComponentActivity

```
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

private val launcher = (this as ComponentActivity).registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.data)
        handleSignInResult(task)
    }
}
```

Comment: This code has to be located somewhere inside a `ComponentActivity`, if it's simply declared at the top level of a file it won't compile, cause there's no `this` in that context.

Comment: Indeed. Silly of me!